# Getting infinity loop when I append div to existing divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I had took some program test online,from there I got some infinity loop error in appending new div to existing div.

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two"></div>
</div>
```

And this JS code is to add new `div`:

```
appendChildren();
function appendChildren() {
    var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");  
    for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement("div");   
        allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
        console.log(allDivs[i]);
    }  
}
```

I want the HTML to look like this:

```
<div id="one">
    <div id="two">   
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

But at run time the program doesn't stop looping. Why? I couldn't guess! So can I run that `appendChildren()` only one time or is there another solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName("div")` is a live collection - it always reflects the actual data.
It means that when you append a `div` item, it is automatically appended to your collection. So, it never ends.

You can copy your collection using `[].slice.call` so that it doesn't change.

Here is the working demo snippet:

```js
function appendChildren() {
  var allDivs = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"));  
  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; i++) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");   
    allDivs[i].appendChild(newDiv);
    console.log(allDivs[i]);
  }  
}

appendChildren();

// For demonstration purposes only:
document.getElementById('html').innerText = document.getElementById('one').outerHTML;
```

```html
<div id="one">
   <div id="two">    
   </div>
</div>

<pre id="html"></pre>
```

The `html` element displays the HTML result - however, it looks bad. You may use developer tools to see the actual structure in a familiar way.